# Convert oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want convert oracleDB to mysql
ref and re_step are int

```
select * from
(select A.*, 
Rownum Rnum from(select * from board order by ref desc ,re_step asc)A)
WHERE Rnum >= ? and Rnum <= ?;
```

Comment: Search for oracle rownum equivalent in mysql and you will find lots. Also by not explaining what you are trying to do you are limiting possible respondents to those with oracle and mysql knowledge.

Comment: The solution depends on precise MySQL version. In 8+ use ROW_NUMBER() in CTE, in 5.x use user-defined variable(s) in the subquery.